# Cannot get the exact wireless protocol at a raspberrypi 4b using header wireless.h

Tags: wifi, raspbian-buster, c, wireless-adapter

I've created a programm in C that runs on raspberry pi4B in order to get the wifi protocol that is supported.

The version of raspbian is :

```
Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
```

According to the official specification the module supports 2.4 GHz and 5.0 GHz IEEE 802.11ac.

However when I use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/wireless.h>


int get_network_type(char *iface, char* protocol)
{
    int sock = -1;
    struct iwreq pwrq;
    memset(&pwrq, 0, sizeof(pwrq));
    strncpy(pwrq.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }
    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIWNAME, &pwrq) != -1)
    {
        if (protocol)
            strncpy(protocol, pwrq.u.name, IFNAMSIZ);
        close(sock);
        return 1;
    }
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ 
  char protocol[IFNAMSIZ]  = {0};
  get_network_type("wlan0",protocol);
  printf("interface %s\n", protocol);
  return 0;
}
```

I always get `IEEE 802.11` even though at the wireless.h header is mentioned that:

```
#define SIOCGIWNAME 0x8B01      /* get name == wireless protocol */
/* SIOCGIWNAME is used to verify the presence of Wireless Extensions.
 * Common values : "IEEE 802.11-DS", "IEEE 802.11-FH", "IEEE 802.11b"...
 * Don't put the name of your driver there, it's useless. */
```

The printout of iwconfig as expected gives the same :

```
wlan0    *IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"xxxxxxxxx"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 7C:39:53:E6:87:67   
          Bit Rate=24 Mb/s   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:36  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Does anyone knows what I have missed here and what should I do in order to get the exact protocol name?

Comment: If I remember correctly protocol version was removed from iwconfig output. I think you can get the version for sure using the interface current bitrate with ['iw'](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw) command. Use `iw dev wlan info` for getting all capabilities. [Here is a related answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62265/linux-find-wifi-networks-protocola-b-g-n-version-of-all-available-access-point)

Comment: You can also read This [C example](https://github.com/Robpol86/libnl/blob/master/example_c/show_wifi_interface.c) and [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601521/how-to-use-the-libnl-library-to-trigger-nl80211-commands) for a starting point